# bash redirect block code output into function

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I've a simple question but don't really find the answer, because most of the time they redirect on a file log instead of a function :/

I simply wish to redirect all STDIN and STDOUT into a function that'll insert everything into cloud watch.

```sh
function insert_logs_into_cloud_watch {
  errorMessage=$1
  echo ${errorMessage}
}

{
  // block of lot of code
} 2>&1 | insert_logs_into_cloud_watch
```

Before I used to insert into a log file by using

```sh
{
  // block of lot of code
} 2>&1 | tee my_log_file.log
```

But how can I do it for a function ?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: This doesn't work because the pipe is sending input to the function's standard input, not as an argument (i.e. `$1`). The right way to do it... depends. Do you want to process the code's output line-by-line, or wait until it finishes and process its entire output as a single item?

Comment: I'm interested for both solutions even if I know I'll go for an output line-by-line. Both solution are interesting to know.. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Actually, there's another question: how do you actually submit the log to CloudWatch? Do you have a command to submit an event log, of something like that?

Comment: I just use the aws command line to send the data to cloud watch ```aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name "$CW_GROUP_NAME" --log-stream-name "$CW_LOG_STREAM_NAME" --log-events timestamp=$TIMESTAMP,message="$errorMessage" --sequence-token $TOKEN```

Of course just before i check if the log stream has been created etc but it's mainly aws command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this depends on whether you want to send each line of output as a separate log event, which would be something like this:

```
function insert_logs_into_cloud_watch {
  while IFS= read -r errorMessage; do
    TIMESTAMP=$(command to get timestamp in appropriate format)
    aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name "$CW_GROUP_NAME" --log-stream-name "$CW_LOG_STREAM_NAME" --log-events timestamp=$TIMESTAMP,message="$errorMessage" --sequence-token $TOKEN
  done
}

{
  // block of lot of code
} 2>&1 | insert_logs_into_cloud_watch
```

Explanation: `read` gets a line at a time from standard input (piped from the code block), then you need to get the current timestamp and submit the line as a log message.

Alternately, if you want to send the entire output as a single message, you could do something like this:

```
errorMessage=$(
  exec 2>&1
  // block of lot of code
)
TIMESTAMP=$(command to get timestamp in appropriate format)
aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name "$CW_GROUP_NAME" --log-stream-name "$CW_LOG_STREAM_NAME" --log-events timestamp=$TIMESTAMP,message="$errorMessage" --sequence-token $TOKEN
```

Explanation: The `exec` command merge standard error into standard output; `$( )` captures that output so that it can be put into the variable.

BTW, there's a bit of a warning here: in both versions the block of code executes in a subshell (in the first because of the pipe, in the second because of `$( )`), meaning that any changes to variables or anything like that are local to the block (i.e. they'll be lost when the block finishes). There are ways to avoid this, but they make the whole thing more complicated.

Comment: thx a lot i tried both solution that's works perfectly !!! Thx a lot for your help :)
also thx for the warning :)

Comment: In your second form, the timestamp will be applied once for the whole code block and at the end of it. This may not be when the error actually happened, especially with larger code blocks.